# Restore deleted message in mutt/neomutt

Tags: mutt

When we delete message in mutt, it is just marked as deleted until we sync the mailbox. Before we sync the mailbox, we can "undelete" the message, removing the delete mark.

My question, is there a way to restore deleted email after we sync the mailbox (the message is already in Trash folder)?

I feel this should be obvious but I cannot find the way to do it in mutt. Is it okay if I manually move the message from the Trash folder to INBOX outside mutt (e.g. with "mv")?

Comment: You're talking about a "trash folder", which `mutt` does not use by default. How have you configured `mutt` to enable this feature (there may be a number of different ways to do this and an answer may well depend on the exact way this was done)?

Comment: Yes, that trash folder. I enabled it by setting the folder in muttrc using `set folder = "..."` and `set trash = "..."`.

Comment: So, can't you just change to the trash folder (with `c`) and then save the mails there to the correct other folder (with `s`)?

Comment: Yes, it works! I did not tried saving before because I thought moving (or saving) it to different folder is not the same as delete/undelete. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `trash` variable in your Mutt configuration to the name of a mailbox (in mbox format), that's the mailbox to which deleted messages will be moved when deleted.

There is nothing else special about the trash mailbox, which means that it's a matter of moving messages out of it to wherever you want to store them if you're going to "undelete" them.  Messages that you *delete* in the trash mailbox will be deleted for good, though.

If your trash mailbox is `+trash`, you may change to that mailbox by pressing <kbd>c</kbd> and then typing `+trash`. Moving a message from the trash mailbox is done by highlighting it in the message list and then pressing <kbd>s</kbd> followed by the destination mailbox's name.